# How to get mean values of grouped variables

Tags: r, dataframe, row, mean

I have a data frame:

```
something<-data.frame( Drug=rep(c(1,2), each=6), Plant=c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2),rep("C",2)), dmso=c(0.407,0.374,0.452,0.429,0.439,0.436,0.441,0.453,0.439,0.436,0.452,0.429), One=c(0.241,0.237,0.455,0.436,0.453,0.433,0.47,0.461,0.453,0.433,0.455,0.436), Two=c(0.065,0.07,0.513,0.542,0.064,0.074,0.5,0.494,0.064,0.074,0.513,0.542), Three=c(0.063,0.068,0.678,0.631,0.068,0.073,0.449,0.521,0.068,0.073,0.678,0.631) )
```

I want to create a new data frame where the rows will represent the means of Plants for drug treatments. 
Ex:
[image]

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate post but I could not find the solution anywhere else. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html):

```
aggregate(.~Drug+Plant,something,mean);
##   Drug Plant   dmso    One    Two  Three
## 1    1     A 0.3905 0.2390 0.0675 0.0655
## 2    2     A 0.4470 0.4655 0.4970 0.4850
## 3    1     B 0.4405 0.4455 0.5275 0.6545
## 4    2     B 0.4375 0.4430 0.0690 0.0705
## 5    1     C 0.4375 0.4430 0.0690 0.0705
## 6    2     C 0.4405 0.4455 0.5275 0.6545
```

---

> ## S3 method for class 'formula'
>   aggregate(*formula*, *data*, *FUN*, ...,
>             *subset*, *na.action* = na.omit)
>
> ...
>
> *formula*
>
> a [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html), such as y ~ x or cbind(y1, y2) ~ x1 + x2, where the y variables are numeric data to be split into groups according to the grouping x variables (usually factors).

The documentation for the special use of the `.` character in the formula can be found on the doc page for [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html):

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see [terms.formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/terms.formula.html). In the context of [update.formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.formula.html), only, it means ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’.

---

[`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) solution:

```
library(data.table);
dt <- as.data.table(something);
dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),.(Drug,Plant)];
##    Drug Plant   dmso    One    Two  Three
## 1:    1     A 0.3905 0.2390 0.0675 0.0655
## 2:    1     B 0.4405 0.4455 0.5275 0.6545
## 3:    1     C 0.4375 0.4430 0.0690 0.0705
## 4:    2     A 0.4470 0.4655 0.4970 0.4850
## 5:    2     B 0.4375 0.4430 0.0690 0.0705
## 6:    2     C 0.4405 0.4455 0.5275 0.6545
```